# Load module from deps' test directory

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to use a module from the test directory of one of my dependencies in the tests of my elixir application. I am wondering if there is a way to do this. Thank you.

I tried `import <module name>`, which gives me a compilation error `elixir module is not loaded and could not be found`.

Comment: Try adding that path (e.g. `deps/<name>/test`) to the list returned by `def elixirc_paths(:test)` in `mix.exs`. That _might_ work. (e.g. `defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support", "deps/foo/test"]`)

Comment: @Dogbert Yes that works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the path to the dependency's `test` folder to the `elixirc_paths` config in `mix.exs`. Since you're using Phoenix, [the default generated `mix.exs`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/d3084804299a9d288266b51aec21541eb1b7c236/installer/templates/phx_single/mix.exs#L13-L33) already includes a custom rule for the `elixirc_paths` for `test` environment like this:

```
defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
```

You just need to add the dependency's `test` folder to that list:

```
defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support", "deps/foo/test"]
```